# Fetching API data via React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am building my first web application with a django backend and react frontend.

I cannot accomplish to fetch the data and print them as an output on my page.
I have no idea why fetching dummy api data from sites like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos is possible, but my own api data not.

Here is a little code snippet where I get the error in my HTML-Inspector:
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/";
    const proxyurl = "https://boiling-tor-92690.herokuapp.com/";

    React.useEffect(() => {
      fetch(proxyurl + url,{
        method:'GET',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }

      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(todos => setTodos(todos))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
    }, []);
    
  
    return (

      <div>

          {todos.map(e =>{
              return <h2>{e.email}</h2>
          })}
            

      </div>
    );
```

Here I had to use a heroku-proxy to fix a CORS-Error

I also tryed it with a functional component and could afford to get my API-Data in my Console but I still got the JSON Parse Error:

```
    componentDidMount() {             
        var self = this;
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/')
          .then(function(response) {
                  return response.json()
          })
          
          .then(function(data) {
            self.setState({ 
                data 
            }, 
            
            () => 

            
            console.log(self.state));


          });
      }
```

Do someone know how to fix this ?

Comment: If you examine the resource you're trying to fetch you can see that the JSON isn't closed properly. Use a different resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an error message that tells you something you expect to be JSON isn't… then **look at the value of what you are trying to parse**. It will probably give you a big clue.

---

The server running at `boiling-tor-92690.herokuapp.com` is not going to access **your** computer when you ask it to fetch `http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/`. It will access its *own* `127.0.0.1:8000` server.

… which will probably not exist, so you'll get an error message, so you don't get JSON, so you'll get the error you got.